# Do solvers use GUB/SOS1 branching?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, branch-and-bound

GUB/SOS1 branching is an old and well-known idea ([see for example page 9 of Jeff Linderoth's notes](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~linderot/classes/ie418/lecture4.pdf)).

Is this implemented in commercial solvers these days?

The [Gurobi documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/wp-content/plugins/hd_documentations/documentation/9.0/refman.pdf) mentions SOS1 constraints, but never mentions SOS1 branching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found in the IBM website that: **CPLEX** automatically converts SOS1 constraints on binary variables into a regular set packing constraint([source](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0eb262af-1bc0-4506-9ab4-d4410ab8ee7c)).

On page 80 of [this](http://egon.cheme.cmu.edu/ewo/docs/LinderothJan07.pdf) presentation by Jeff Linderoth, it is mentioned that some noncommercial solvers like **CBC** and **Ip_solve** SOS(2) branching while **CBC** and **MINTO** equipped with GUB branching.

Answer (score 9):

If you accept non-commercial solvers too, then [SCIP](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.2/html/RN32.php) seems to have it. From the link:

> `constraints/sos1/branchingrule` to decide whether to use neighborhood, bipartite, or SOS1 branching...

AIMMS also seems to have a mention of SOS1 branching according to page 9 of [this](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf) manual.

Comment: To complete @EhsanK said, SCIP has a facility to deal with it. Please, see this [link](https://scip.zib.de/workshop2014/parametertuning.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite common, on top of what other people mentioned, I believe MINOTAUR and Couenne support that too, and as of the December release, so will Octeract Engine.